# Powershell Function to autocomplete and change directory

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have the following Powershell function to set a directory, nice and simple. When i type dev, auto complete works for the items inside the directory..

Example: dev ./project

However when pressing enter, the directory changes to the set-location 'E:\OneDrive\Website Workspace\', not it's child 'E:\OneDrive\Website Workspace\project'.. How would i go about this correctly.

```
function dev {
    set-location 'E:\OneDrive\Website Workspace\'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use PS drives

```
New-PSDrive -Name ws -PSProvider filesystem -Root 'E:\OneDrive\Website Workspace\'
get-childitem ws:\project
```

You just have to put the first line into you profile.

Comment: I would like like to be able to run a few additional functions, like activating a virtual environment.. Would that be possible using this technique?

Comment: I don't know, you should try.